# Plot clusters of observations which represent a time series

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I am using `dtwclust` package to cluster a data frame contains multivariate time series data. After clustering these data, I would like to produce a plot presenting observation in $k$ groups according tot the cluster, not the time series data!

```
dtw_cluster2 = tsclust(sample_data, type="partitional",k=6,preproc = zscore,distance="dtw_basic",centroid = "pam",trace=T)
```

then to plot,

```
plot(dtw_cluster2)
```

and I got:[image]

I don't want these plots! I want the cluster of observations. I tried to extract the clusters from `tsclust()` as `dtw_cluster2$cluster` but I got an error `"$ operator not defined for this S4 class"`.

My data set looks like

```
 V1        V2         V3         V4          V5         V6         V7
1  0 0.1182197 0.09057301 0.08089888 0.003350084 0.00000000 0.00000000
2  0 0.1276078 0.09242144 0.01348315 0.060301508 0.02245599 0.02298152
3  0 0.1369958 0.12569316 0.03595506 0.159128978 0.04491198 0.04596305
4  0 0.1029207 0.10166359 0.08089888 0.201005025 0.06736798 0.06894457
5  0 0.1585535 0.14510166 0.08089888 0.112227806 0.08982397 0.09192609
6  0 0.1488178 0.00000000 0.07415730 0.212730318 0.11227996 0.11490761
```

edit

I want to plot the observations according to the clusters in something like this "knowing that I am using `dtw` distance":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the result, you can see this:

```
str(dtw_cluster2)

Formal class 'PartitionalTSClusters' [package "dtwclust"] with 20 slots
  #.. (NB here there are things I've skipped )
  ..@ distance : chr "dtw_basic"
  ..@ centroid : chr "pam"
  ..@ preproc  : chr "zscore"
  ..@ k        : int 2
  ..@ cluster  : int [1:6] 1 1 1 2 1 2
  #.. (NB here there are things I've skipped )
```

So you can extract the cluster in this way:

```
dtw_cluster2@cluster
[1] 1 1 1 2 1 2
```

Given:

```
library(dtwclust)
dtw_cluster2 <- tsclust(sample_data, type="partitional",
                                     k=2,
                                     preproc = zscore,
                                     distance="dtw_basic",
                                     centroid = "pam",
                                     trace=T)
```

---

with data:

```
sample_data <-
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(0.1182197, 
0.1276078, 0.1369958, 0.1029207, 0.1585535, 0.1488178), V3 = c(0.09057301, 
0.09242144, 0.12569316, 0.10166359, 0.14510166, 0), V4 = c(0.08089888, 
0.01348315, 0.03595506, 0.08089888, 0.08089888, 0.0741573), V5 = c(0.003350084, 
0.060301508, 0.159128978, 0.201005025, 0.112227806, 0.212730318
), V6 = c(0, 0.02245599, 0.04491198, 0.06736798, 0.08982397, 
0.11227996), V7 = c(0, 0.02298152, 0.04596305, 0.06894457, 0.09192609, 
0.11490761)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how to plot the observations according to the clusters?

Comment: @Flore hi could you explain better the desired output? Your plot is already faceted by clusters.

Comment: It's a bit more clear. What do you desired in the x and y axis?

Comment: I am not sure! but I  think x represents the observations from the multivariate time series in CLUSTERS and y would be the distance. Are there other options for x and y?

Comment: Each time series is univariate as I see, and each one has more than 1 observation. Also the distance, as you can see with `dtw_cluster2@distmat`, are one for each combination of the ts. I've the idea that the scatter plot does not fit well for this analysis. Try to read [this paper](http://lig-membres.imag.fr/bisson/cours/M2INFO-AIW-ML/papers/PetitJean11.pdf) to clarify a bit.

Comment: Just for me to understand: my data is a multivariate time series of 6000 observations where each observation is a line consist of all variables(7) values. Consequently, I use dtw to compute the distance between all pairs of observations. I have a 6000*6000  distance matrix.

Comment: so, using tsclust function for clustering multivariate time series, we can't have a scatter plot for clusters?

Comment: Ok that's clear: the fact is that the scatter plot you want need one x and one y coordinates for each ts (and color for clusters). Which one coordinates x and y are you going to plot? You said "x represents the observations from the multivariate time series in CLUSTERS and y would be the distance", which observation? and which distance for each ts? I suppose you cannot flatten the ts in that way. But maybe someone has a better answer!